# PySpark - Reading data from MongoDB using mongo-spark connector results in MongoQueryException for exceeding document size

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying MongoDB's new Spark [connector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark) to read data from MongoDB. I supplied the DB and collection details to Spark conf object while starting the application. And then use the following piece of code to read to a dataframe

```
reader = sqlContext.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
df = reader.options(partitioner='MongoSplitVectorPartitioner').load()
```

Then write this dataframe to a parquet file

```
df.write.parquet(/destination/path)
```

It starts a job with a number of tasks which all succeed except the last task, which fails the whole writing job. I'm getting an exception on document size being greater than 16 MB.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:269)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:148)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:148)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 16493 and error message 'Tried to create string longer than 16MB' on server xx.xxx.xx.xx:27018
at com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getQueryFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:131)
at com.mongodb.connection.GetMoreProtocol.execute(GetMoreProtocol.java:96)
at com.mongodb.connection.GetMoreProtocol.execute(GetMoreProtocol.java:49)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:159)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:286)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.getMore(DefaultServerConnection.java:251)
at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.getMore(QueryBatchCursor.java:218)
at com.mongodb.operation.QueryBatchCursor.hasNext(QueryBatchCursor.java:103)
at com.mongodb.MongoBatchCursorAdapter.hasNext(MongoBatchCursorAdapter.java:46)
at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:41)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.next(SerDeUtil.scala:118)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.next(SerDeUtil.scala:110)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1801)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)
```

I do not maintain the Mongo database. So I'm not sure how a document greater than 16 MB exists in first place. Could probably be use of GridFS.
Is there a way I can skip processing the bad records?

I tried using a udf to filter but it also failed on the same error

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col

size_filter_udf = udf(lambda entry: sys.getsizeof(entry), IntegerType())

filtered_df = df.where(size_filter_udf(col("caseNotes")) < 16000000)

filtered_df.write.parquet(/destination/path)
```

Comment: Try connecting via [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) and check whether any documents are greater than 16MB/GridFS. Another thing you could try is removed the splitVector and just use `df = sqlContext.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have data inside mongodb that looks to be corrupt. If you can determine the document you may be able to fix it manually.